# FLUTTER - Error: No profiles for 'xxx' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App

Tags: xcode, flutter

I am trying to run my flutter app on my ios simulator after including firebase_core in my project. It was working fine before including **firebase_core: ^0.7.0**. But now, my build is getting failed with the following errors.

```
    Building com.xxx.xxx for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project:
CAV65P4ALS
Running pod install...                                              1.5s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            1.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[45442]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x205394188) and
    ?? (0x1145342b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[45442]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x2053941d8) and ??
    (0x114534308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/gauravdangi/Development/work/examples/xxx/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/gauravdangi/Development/work/examples/xxx/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    error: No profiles for 'com.xxx.xxx' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App
    Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.xxx.xxx'. Automatic signing is
    disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass
    -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/gauravdangi/Development/work/examples/xxx/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project
    'Pods')
    /Users/gauravdangi/Development/work/examples/xxx/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/gauravdangi/Development/work/examples/xxx/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
```

I tried Signing in to get a Signing certificate in code and got the following error:

> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

[image: Screensgot of code screen]

I have been trying to resolve this issue but no luck. Do I need a real iOS device just to run my app on the simulator?
Also, I have not purchased the apple developer account. Do I need to purchase it for testing my app on the simulator, because as far as I know, we need to purchase only if we decide to publish our app on the apple store.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I'm having the same problem.